# PayPal Plus Payment language

Tags: paypal, paypal-plus

when paying with PayPal Plus I get a selection of possible payment methods (SEPA, credit card, ...) when paying in the store. I myself always see these in German, but I wonder if these are automatically translated? Does anyone know if PayPal evaluates the ordering country or do they all see the German language? I have found little to no information on this. Have only often read that you can not customize, but nothing on the subject of translation.

Thanks for ur help guys!

I try to contact the Support and search for that topic on google. But I have not received any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: this answer applies most definitely to the behavior of [standard JS SDK integration buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). The DE-specific "PayPal Plus" product asked about in this question is somewhat unique as PayPal integrations go, and so things might be different with PayPal Plus.

---

By default the SEPA button will only present to payers with a German IP. In sandbox mode, a different country IP can be simulated with e.g. `&buyer-country=US` (buyer-country in live mode will prevent the SDK from loading)

For the language used in the buttons, by default the browser's first requested one is used (e.g. the top entry in `chrome://settings/languages`)

If necessary that IP button language could be overridden for the purposes of matching the language elsewhere on the page, using e.g. `&locale=en_US` or de_DE. This is not recommended as it's usually better for payers to see what the browser requested, but the feature is available for pages that have specific localization needs.

As for the language that appears when a button is clicked and a checkout starts, this is more complex. First the IP address of the payer is taken into effect to determine their country. If `locale` was specified *and its specified language **is** one of the languages available for that country IP*, that locale language is used. Otherwise, if a browser language is set and that language is one of the available ones for that country IP, that browser requested language is used. Otherwise it defaults to the primary language available for that country IP. Stored cookies from previous PayPal checkouts/logins using that browser could also have an effect; test in private/incognito if you need to see the behavior without cookies.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Preston PHX for your detailed response. Your information is helpful to me. Many thanks, and I wish you a successful day!